# Implementing a lexer using the Free Monad

Tags: parsing, haskell, monads, lexer, free-monad

I am thinking about a use case of the [free monad](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/free) which would be a simple lexing DSL. So far I came up with some primitive operations:

```
data LexF r where
  POP  :: (Char -> r) -> LexF r
  PEEK :: (Char -> r) -> LexF r
  FAIL :: LexF r
  ...

instance Functor LexF where
  ...

type Lex = Free LexF
```

The problem I encounter is that I would like to have a `CHOICE` primitive that would describe an operation of trying to execute one parser and in case of failure fallback to another. Something like `CHOICE :: LexF r -> LexF r -> (r -> r) -> LexF r`...

...and here the stairs begin. Since `r` is preset at contravariant position, it is impossible (is it?) to create a valid `Functor` instance for `Op`. I came up with some other idea, which was to generalize over the type of alternative lexers, so `CHOICE :: LexF a -> LexF a -> (a -> r) -> LexF r` – now it works as a `Functor`, though the problem is with thawing it into `Free`, as I would normally do it with `liftF`:

```
choice :: OpF a -> OpF a -> OpF a
choice c1 c2 = liftF $ CHOICE _ _ id  -- how to fill the holes :: Op a ?
```

I am really running out of any ideas. This of course generalizes to nearly all other combinators, I just find `CHOICE` a good minimal case. How to tackle it? I am okay to hear that this example is totally broken and it just won't work with `Free` as I would like to. But therefore, does it even make sense to write lexers/parsers in this manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule when working with free monads, you don't want to introduce primitives for "monadic control".  For example, a `SEQUENCE` primitive would be ill-advised, because the free monad itself provides sequencing.  Likewise, a `CHOICE` primitive is ill-advised because this should be provided by a free
`MonadPlus`.

Now, there is [no free `MonadPlus`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32185389/what-was-wrong-with-control-monadplus-free) in modern versions of `free` because equivalent functionality is provided by a free monad transformer over a list base monad, namely `FreeT f []`.  So, what you probably want is to define:

```
data LexF r where
  POP  :: (Char -> r) -> LexF r
  PEEK :: (Char -> r) -> LexF r
deriving instance Functor LexF
type Lex = FreeT LexF []

pop :: (Char -> a) -> Lex a
pop f = liftF $ POP f

peek :: (Char -> a) -> Lex a
peek f = liftF $ PEEK f
```

but no `FAIL` or `CHOICE` primitives.

If you were to define `fail` and `choice` combinators, they would be defined by means of the list base monad using transformer magic:

```
fail :: Lex a
fail = empty

choice :: Lex a -> Lex a -> Lex a
choice = (<|>)
```

though there's no actual reason to define these.

**SPOILERS** follow...  Anyway, you can now write things like:

```
anyChar :: Lex Char
anyChar = pop id

char :: Char -> Lex Char
char c = do
  c' <- anyChar
  guard $ c == c'
  return c'

a_or_b :: Lex Char
a_or_b = char 'a' <|> char 'b'
```

With an interpreter for your monad primitives, in this case intrepreting them to the `StateT String []` AKA `String -> [(a,String)]` monad:

```
type Parser = StateT String []
runLex :: Lex a -> Parser a
runLex = iterTM go
  where go :: LexF (Parser a) -> Parser a
        go (POP f) = StateT pop' >>= f
          where pop' (c:cs) = [(c,cs)]
                pop' _      = []
        go (PEEK f) = StateT peek' >>= f
          where peek' (c:cs) = [(c,c:cs)]
                peek' _      = []
parse :: Lex a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse = runStateT . runLex
```

you can then:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  let test = parse a_or_b
  print $ test "abc"
  print $ test "bca"
  print $ test "cde"
```

The full example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wall #-}

import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.Trans.Free

data LexF r where
  POP  :: (Char -> r) -> LexF r
  PEEK :: (Char -> r) -> LexF r
deriving instance Functor LexF
type Lex = FreeT LexF []

pop :: (Char -> a) -> Lex a
pop f = liftF $ POP f

peek :: (Char -> a) -> Lex a
peek f = liftF $ PEEK f

anyChar :: Lex Char
anyChar = pop id

char :: Char -> Lex Char
char c = do
  c' <- anyChar
  guard $ c == c'
  return c'

a_or_b :: Lex Char
a_or_b = char 'a' <|> char 'b'

type Parser = StateT String []
runLex :: Lex a -> Parser a
runLex = iterTM go
  where go :: LexF (Parser a) -> Parser a
        go (POP f) = StateT pop' >>= f
          where pop' (c:cs) = [(c,cs)]
                pop' _      = []
        go (PEEK f) = StateT peek' >>= f
          where peek' (c:cs) = [(c,c:cs)]
                peek' _      = []
parse :: Lex a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse = runStateT . runLex

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let test = parse a_or_b
  print $ test "abc"
  print $ test "bca"
  print $ test "cde"
```